# Intermittent permissions issues publishing to pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We are getting intermittent permissions issues publishing from a GCP Kubernetes container to a GCP pub/sub.  In one process/pid, we'll see ~50 messages go through, a few seconds of `The request is missing a valid API key` followed by ~50 messages going through.  The full error message looks like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

---

Our setup:

- We setup a `Workload Identity User` for our Kubernetes pod.
- We linked that `Workload Identity User` to a service account.
- We gave that service account publishing rights on the pub/sub topic.
- We are using PHP with the vendor package google/cloud-pubsub version 1.30.2

---

I'd say 99% of our messages go through.  But a few times a day, we get outages where the messages do not go through for a few seconds with the permissions error, and then publishing starts working again a few seconds later.

I saw another post suggesting perhaps `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` could be getting in the way.  We verified we are not setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as we are relying on the service account to give the docker containers publish access to the pub/sub topic.

An early thought experiment was suspicious of a race condition with docker images coming online/offline.  But given we see a few seconds of permissions issues in a long running process makes us think it's likely something else.  Does anyone have any ideas or things we should look at?

We appreciate the help!

**UPDATE 2021-09-28:** 
Here are our logs from yesterday on when and how many permissions errors we saw against when and how many publishes went through. This is showing how many events happened per hour.  This came from one docker instance:

Permissions issues:

```
fgrep 'The request is missing a valid API key' /log/file/was/here.log | perl -ne '/(Sep 27 [0-9]{2}):.*/; print $1 . "\n"' | uniq -c
     38 Sep 27 06
     90 Sep 27 07
    176 Sep 27 17
    186 Sep 27 18
     54 Sep 27 19
```

No permissions issues:

```
fgrep 'published index requeue' /log/file/was/here.log | perl -ne '/(Sep 27 [0-9]{2}):.*/; print $1 . "\n"' | uniq -c
    571 Sep 27 00
    900 Sep 27 01
   1117 Sep 27 02
    562 Sep 27 03
   3396 Sep 27 04
   1767 Sep 27 05
   4568 Sep 27 06
   3857 Sep 27 07
   2160 Sep 27 08
     74 Sep 27 09
    218 Sep 27 10
     55 Sep 27 11
   1992 Sep 27 12
   4376 Sep 27 13
    482 Sep 27 14
    839 Sep 27 15
   3533 Sep 27 16
   8903 Sep 27 17
  10067 Sep 27 18
   9098 Sep 27 19
   1006 Sep 27 20
   2932 Sep 27 21
    919 Sep 27 22
   1104 Sep 27 23
```

The sum of these comes to `544 failed` and `64496 success` which is a failure rate of about `.84%` when averaged over the whole day.  If looking at an hour we saw failures such as 1800Z, we see `186 failed` and `10067 success` or a failure rate of `1.8%` for the 1800Z hour

**UPDATE 2021-09-28 part 2:**
Just dove into one of those hours we saw failures and grouped it down to the minute.

Permissions issues in the 1800Z hour:

```
fgrep 'The request is missing a valid API key' /log/file/was/here.log | perl -ne '/(Sep 27 18:[0-9]{2}):.*/; print $1 . "\n"' | uniq -c
      4 Sep 27 18:01
      2 Sep 27 18:02
      2 Sep 27 18:03
      2 Sep 27 18:04
      2 Sep 27 18:05
     16 Sep 27 18:10
      6 Sep 27 18:12
      6 Sep 27 18:16
      2 Sep 27 18:20
      4 Sep 27 18:21
      2 Sep 27 18:30
      2 Sep 27 18:32
      2 Sep 27 18:33
      2 Sep 27 18:34
     14 Sep 27 18:35
      8 Sep 27 18:36
      8 Sep 27 18:37
      2 Sep 27 18:38
      2 Sep 27 18:40
      8 Sep 27 18:41
      8 Sep 27 18:42
      8 Sep 27 18:43
     10 Sep 27 18:44
     10 Sep 27 18:45
     38 Sep 27 18:46
      4 Sep 27 18:47
      8 Sep 27 18:51
      4 Sep 27 18:58
```

No permissions issues in the 1800Z hour:

```
fgrep 'published index requeue' /log/file/was/here.log | perl -ne '/(Sep 27 18:[0-9]{2}):.*/; print $1 . "\n"' | uniq -c
    249 Sep 27 18:00
    187 Sep 27 18:01
    156 Sep 27 18:02
    266 Sep 27 18:03
    302 Sep 27 18:04
    149 Sep 27 18:05
     29 Sep 27 18:06
    572 Sep 27 18:07
    499 Sep 27 18:08
    395 Sep 27 18:09
    189 Sep 27 18:10
    257 Sep 27 18:11
    194 Sep 27 18:12
    185 Sep 27 18:13
     94 Sep 27 18:14
     49 Sep 27 18:15
     71 Sep 27 18:16
     77 Sep 27 18:17
     36 Sep 27 18:18
     34 Sep 27 18:19
     73 Sep 27 18:20
    114 Sep 27 18:21
     82 Sep 27 18:22
     87 Sep 27 18:23
     20 Sep 27 18:24
     39 Sep 27 18:25
     56 Sep 27 18:26
     31 Sep 27 18:27
     79 Sep 27 18:28
     82 Sep 27 18:29
    270 Sep 27 18:30
     32 Sep 27 18:31
    174 Sep 27 18:32
    165 Sep 27 18:33
     91 Sep 27 18:34
    213 Sep 27 18:35
    243 Sep 27 18:36
    208 Sep 27 18:37
     92 Sep 27 18:38
     76 Sep 27 18:39
    211 Sep 27 18:40
    269 Sep 27 18:41
    164 Sep 27 18:42
    322 Sep 27 18:43
    228 Sep 27 18:44
    294 Sep 27 18:45
    242 Sep 27 18:46
    318 Sep 27 18:47
    145 Sep 27 18:48
     42 Sep 27 18:49
    115 Sep 27 18:50
    206 Sep 27 18:51
    214 Sep 27 18:52
    213 Sep 27 18:53
    169 Sep 27 18:54
    169 Sep 27 18:55
    208 Sep 27 18:56
    190 Sep 27 18:57
     88 Sep 27 18:58
     43 Sep 27 18:59
```

Comment: Do you notice if there is a time interval between the error 403 when it occurs? Like does it occur every hour, two hours, etc.?

Comment: @RiccoD, that's a good question.  Just grouped permissions issues and successful pushes by hour.  Updated the original question with that data.  Would be happy to break it up in a different way if you think it's provide any more insights?

Comment: I think you have a well presented data with regards to the timing of 403 issue =)

Comment: When did you start to notice the intermittent 403 errors? I just noticed that there is an ongoing connectivity issue with Docker workloads in GKE. See https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/QSirAFiyN5yMeeE6GNxq

Comment: Hey @RiccoD!  Thanks again for the followup!  We weren't seeing connectivity issues to a Fastly destination as the outage report suggests.  We checked the logs though to see if the permissions errors lined up with the outage.  Looks like they don't; we've been seeing the errors since we shipped the product.  And we've seen a few more 403 errors today.  The errors today didn't start until 16:13Z.  Since 16:13Z though, we are seeing a few 403 errors per minute.   Do you have any more ideas we could check?  We don't look close to a rate limit but do you think its possible its a rate limit issue?

Comment: I don't think it is the rate limit as well. There might be something happening at 16:00Z on your setup. It might be better to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2) if you have an existing support package or free trial credits as they have the proper tools to further look into this.

Comment: I'd love to reach out to Google support.  We are a pre-revenue startup and the support options are pretty expensive for us.  You mentioned free trial credits.  We don't see those in the GCP console.  Are they something we may have missed out on?  Or maybe I'm not looking in the right places?

Comment: If your account is newly created it should have a $300 free trial credits. As long as your free trial credits exist, you can reach out to the GCP support. See [reference](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#free-trial) for more details.